# jQuery if statement with more conditions

Tags: jquery

I want to disable css when going through the if statement. But when I add another condition to the if statement the functions is not working.

Here is the function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#exampleSelect1").change(function (){
    $('#form-zonwering').css('display','block');
    if($("#exampleSelect1 option:selected").val()!= "Greenline_Veranda" || "Profiline_Veranda"){
        $('#form-zonwering').css('display','none');}
  });
});
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: can you clarify a bit more? I understood almost nothing from your description and example

Comment: https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/03/14/better-ways-of-comparing-a-javascript-string-to-multiple-values/

Comment: This OR condition is not correct `$("#exampleSelect1 option:selected").val()!= "Greenline_Veranda" || "Profiline_Veranda")`

Answer (score 0):

When placing multiple conditions in an `if` statement you need to duplicate them completely. Also note that you can call `val()` directly on the `select` element, not the chosen `option`.

```
var val = $("#exampleSelect1").val();
if (val != "Greenline_Veranda" && val != "Profiline_Veranda") {
    $('#form-zonwering').css('display', 'none');
}
```

However you should note that you can make the logic more succinct by using jQuery's `toggle()` method instead:

```
$("#exampleSelect1").change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $('#form-zonwering').toggle(val != 'Greenline_Veranda' && val != 'Profiline_Veranda');
});
```